# Dynamic frame content python3 tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, widget

Ok so, I am building an Sqlite browser in python(3) tkinter 
Here is the problem. If you look at my code

The code  derived from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter

## License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from sqlite3 import *
import operator

file = 'chinook.db'
conn = connect(file)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'")
tables = c.fetchall()
tmplist = []
for i in tables:
    tmplist.append(i[0])
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
print("done",tables)

global tabnam
tabnam = ''
def asign(sigh): #ok, yeah it was late and i didnt care much about naming convention
    tabnam = sigh
    #this function is supposed to assign the value given to the variable


def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func
    #wrapper function
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC Client")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

       self.show_frame(StartPage)

       def show_frame(self, cont):

           frame = self.frames[cont]
           frame.tkraise()
print("done")

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = ttk.Label(self, text=file, font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        for i in tmplist:

            button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page " + str(i),
                       command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
            button.pack()


print("done")

class PageOne(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text='values', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)



        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        try:
            c.execute("select * from {y}".format(y=tabnam))

            for i in c.fetchall():
                label = ttk.Label(text=i[0], font=LARGE_FONT)
                label.pack(pady=10,padx=20)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e) # the error message indicates that the string formating identifies tabnam as "  "
print("done")



app = SeaofBTCapp()
print("done")
app.mainloop()
print("done")
```

I'm trying to iterate an sqlite query. MEANING: i made it so that for every table, tkinter creates a button. This works. Tkinter displays a button with the name of every table. Now I want this code to be able to display every value in that table when that button is clicked. I have made a wrapping function to show the frame and reassign the current value of tabnam, the variable that represents the table name clicked by the user ; When the button is clicked, I reassign the value of a global variable named `tabnam` . But before the the buttons are even made, python just goes ahead and executes the query (thats yet to be formatted because user hasnt clicked button) and throws me an error. How do i fix this?

Comment: "When the button is clicked, I reassign the value of a global variable named tabnam." Where exactly in the code are you doing this?

Comment: This is way too much code for your problem. Please can you review this and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, your indentation is broken. I cannot run this code as it currently stands.